# Server too busy

Tags: c#, iis

Constantemente tenho essa situação: `Server Too Busy` quando rodo a minha aplicação webforms. O que eu devo fazer para resolver essa situação? Penso ser o IIS Express, mas já me disseram que pode ser banco de dados.

Comment: Há algum código de erro na página de erro que o iis retorna?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Tente seguir esses passos

Abra sua aplicação, vá em

Properties --> Web Tab  -->  Servers --> E marque (Use Local IIS  Web Server)  e clique em   Create Virtual Directory.

Rode sua aplicação.

Volte para a Web Tab e clique em Use Visual Studio  Development  Server

Fonte:[http://forums.asp.net/t/1911697.aspx?+Server+Too+Busy+Error+Page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1911697.aspx?%20Server%20Too%20Busy%20Error%20Page)

Comment: Vou testar hoje o dia todo e depois posto o resultado. Até agora não deu problema, mas esse erro dá esporadicamente, logo preciso testar bem, ok? Mas não deixarei de dar um feedback da situação.

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema pode ser causado por muitos motivos e sem poder analisar vários pontos fica difícil mas eu sugiro que você coloque o atributo delayNotificationTimeout dentro da tag httpRuntime que fica dentro da tag System.web do web.config sua aplicação, segue a cópia de uma tag que uso:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="600" enableVersionHeader="false" delayNotificationTimeout="20" />
```

Por favor comente se resolveu o problema pois caso não funcione tento ajudar de outra forma.

Comment: Faltou o segue a cópia

Comment: Não sei como eu faço para incluir essa tag no System.web. Não consigo editar.

Comment: Quando coloquei o XML o stackoverflow cortou. Agora está ok. O arquivo é o web.config. Lá tem uma tag system.web com a tag httpRuntime dentro. Sds.

Comment: Vou testar hoje o dia todo e depois posto o resultado. Até agora não deu problema, mas esse erro dá esporadicamente, logo preciso testar bem, ok? Mas não deixarei de dar um feedback da situação.